# Microsoft C# Extension for VSCode cannot find .NET Core SDK

Tags: .net, visual-studio-code, omnisharp

### Issue Description

I installed the .NET Core 3.1.0 SDK, tried to add the Microsoft C# extension to VSCode and got the following popup:

[image: 46F9F9AB-EF0C-4DC8-B18A-0532E2DDEDF2_4_5005_c]

I'm quite sure I've installed everything correctly. After messing with this for long enough, I tried uninstalling all SDKs and runtimes on my machine following the steps listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/versions/remove-runtime-sdk-versions?tabs=macos). Reinstalled SDK 3.1.0 and the issue persisted.

### Steps to Reproduce

Not quite sure how this could be reproduced since it seems like a rare problem! I did have VS Community installed on my machine when the issue first occurred, but I've since uninstalled it and all of the associated SDKs but the issue is still happening.

### Expected Behavior

For the extension to be able to find the SDK, since I can run all `dotnet` commands from my terminal just fine.

### Actual Behavior

It can't find it.

### Logs

#### OmniSharp log

```
<details>Starting OmniSharp server at 1/11/2020, 12:55:00 PM
    Target: /Users/finley/dev/dotnet/DatingApp/DatingApp.API

OmniSharp server started.
    Path: /Users/finley/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.csharp-1.21.9/.omnisharp/1.34.9/run
    PID: 3072

[info]: OmniSharp.Stdio.Host
        Starting OmniSharp on MacOS 10.15.2 (x64)
[info]: OmniSharp.Services.DotNetCliService
        DotNetPath set to dotnet
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.Discovery.MSBuildLocator
        Located 1 MSBuild instance(s)
            1: StandAlone 16.3 - "/Users/finley/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.csharp-1.21.9/.omnisharp/1.34.9/omnisharp/.msbuild/Current/Bin"
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.Discovery.MSBuildLocator
        MSBUILD_EXE_PATH environment variable set to '/Users/finley/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.csharp-1.21.9/.omnisharp/1.34.9/omnisharp/.msbuild/Current/Bin/MSBuild.dll'
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.Discovery.MSBuildLocator
        Registered MSBuild instance: StandAlone 16.3 - "/Users/finley/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.csharp-1.21.9/.omnisharp/1.34.9/omnisharp/.msbuild/Current/Bin"
            CscToolExe = csc.exe
            MSBuildToolsPath = /Users/finley/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.csharp-1.21.9/.omnisharp/1.34.9/omnisharp/.msbuild/Current/Bin
            CscToolPath = /Users/finley/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.csharp-1.21.9/.omnisharp/1.34.9/omnisharp/.msbuild/Current/Bin/Roslyn
            BypassFrameworkInstallChecks = true
            MSBuildExtensionsPath = /Users/finley/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.csharp-1.21.9/.omnisharp/1.34.9/omnisharp/.msbuild
[info]: OmniSharp.Cake.CakeProjectSystem
        Detecting Cake files in '/Users/finley/dev/dotnet/DatingApp/DatingApp.API'.
[info]: OmniSharp.Cake.CakeProjectSystem
        Could not find any Cake files
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectSystem
        No solution files found in '/Users/finley/dev/dotnet/DatingApp/DatingApp.API'
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Queue project update for '/Users/finley/dev/dotnet/DatingApp/DatingApp.API/DatingApp.API.csproj'
[info]: OmniSharp.Script.ScriptProjectSystem
        Detecting CSX files in '/Users/finley/dev/dotnet/DatingApp/DatingApp.API'.
[info]: OmniSharp.Script.ScriptProjectSystem
        Could not find any CSX files
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
        Invoking Workspace Options Provider: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.CSharpFormattingWorkspaceOptionsProvider, Order: 0
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
        Invoking Workspace Options Provider: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.RenameWorkspaceOptionsProvider, Order: 100
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
        Invoking Workspace Options Provider: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.EditorConfigWorkspaceOptionsProvider, Order: 200
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
        Configuration finished.
[info]: OmniSharp.Stdio.Host
        Omnisharp server running using Stdio at location '/Users/finley/dev/dotnet/DatingApp/DatingApp.API' on host 2959.
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Loading project: /Users/finley/dev/dotnet/DatingApp/DatingApp.API/DatingApp.API.csproj
  It was not possible to find any installed .NET Core SDKs
  Did you mean to run .NET Core SDK commands? Install a .NET Core SDK from:
      https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
[warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Failed to load project file '/Users/finley/dev/dotnet/DatingApp/DatingApp.API/DatingApp.API.csproj'.
/Users/finley/dev/dotnet/DatingApp/DatingApp.API/DatingApp.API.csproj(1,1)
Microsoft.Build.Exceptions.InvalidProjectFileException: The SDK 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web' specified could not be found.  /Users/finley/dev/dotnet/DatingApp/DatingApp.API/DatingApp.API.csproj
  at Microsoft.Build.Shared.ProjectErrorUtilities.ThrowInvalidProject (System.String errorSubCategoryResourceName, Microsoft.Build.Shared.IElementLocation elementLocation, System.String resourceName, System.Object[] args) [0x00040] in <10b73e4bf233421cae439ef765e97ef0>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Shared.ProjectErrorUtilities.VerifyThrowInvalidProject[T1] (System.Boolean condition, System.String errorSubCategoryResourceName, Microsoft.Build.Shared.IElementLocation elementLocation, System.String resourceName, T1 arg0) [0x00003] in <10b73e4bf233421cae439ef765e97ef0>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Shared.ProjectErrorUtilities.ThrowInvalidProject[T1] (Microsoft.Build.Shared.IElementLocation elementLocation, System.String resourceName, T1 arg0) [0x00000] in <10b73e4bf233421cae439ef765e97ef0>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4[P,I,M,D].ExpandAndLoadImportsFromUnescapedImportExpressionConditioned (System.String directoryOfImportingFile, Microsoft.Build.Construction.ProjectImportElement importElement, System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Microsoft.Build.Construction.ProjectRootElement]& projects, Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.SdkResolution.SdkResult& sdkResult, System.Boolean throwOnFileNotExistsError) [0x00254] in <10b73e4bf233421cae439ef765e97ef0>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4[P,I,M,D].ExpandAndLoadImports (System.String directoryOfImportingFile, Microsoft.Build.Construction.ProjectImportElement importElement, Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.SdkResolution.SdkResult& sdkResult) [0x00027] in <10b73e4bf233421cae439ef765e97ef0>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4[P,I,M,D].EvaluateImportElement (System.String directoryOfImportingFile, Microsoft.Build.Construction.ProjectImportElement importElement) [0x0000d] in <10b73e4bf233421cae439ef765e97ef0>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4[P,I,M,D].PerformDepthFirstPass (Microsoft.Build.Construction.ProjectRootElement currentProjectOrImport) [0x000e6] in <10b73e4bf233421cae439ef765e97ef0>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4[P,I,M,D].Evaluate (Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.Logging.ILoggingService loggingService, Microsoft.Build.Framework.BuildEventContext buildEventContext) [0x0011c] in <10b73e4bf233421cae439ef765e97ef0>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4[P,I,M,D].Evaluate (Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.IEvaluatorData`4[P,I,M,D] data, Microsoft.Build.Construction.ProjectRootElement root, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings, System.Int32 maxNodeCount, Microsoft.Build.Collections.PropertyDictionary`1[T] environmentProperties, Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.Logging.ILoggingService loggingService, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.IItemFactory`2[S,T] itemFactory, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.IToolsetProvider toolsetProvider, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectRootElementCacheBase projectRootElementCache, Microsoft.Build.Framework.BuildEventContext buildEventContext, Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.SdkResolution.ISdkResolverService sdkResolverService, System.Int32 submissionId, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Context.EvaluationContext evaluationContext, System.Boolean interactive) [0x0002f] in <10b73e4bf233421cae439ef765e97ef0>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project.Reevaluate (Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.Logging.ILoggingService loggingServiceForEvaluation, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Context.EvaluationContext evaluationContext) [0x0005e] in <10b73e4bf233421cae439ef765e97ef0>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project.ReevaluateIfNecessary (Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.Logging.ILoggingService loggingServiceForEvaluation, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Context.EvaluationContext evaluationContext) [0x00035] in <10b73e4bf233421cae439ef765e97ef0>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project.ReevaluateIfNecessary (Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.Logging.ILoggingService loggingServiceForEvaluation, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Context.EvaluationContext evaluationContext) [0x00000] in <10b73e4bf233421cae439ef765e97ef0>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project.ReevaluateIfNecessary (Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Context.EvaluationContext evaluationContext) [0x00007] in <10b73e4bf233421cae439ef765e97ef0>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project.Initialize (System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[TKey,TValue] globalProperties, System.String toolsVersion, System.String subToolsetVersion, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Context.EvaluationContext evaluationContext) [0x00126] in <10b73e4bf233421cae439ef765e97ef0>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project..ctor (System.String projectFile, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[TKey,TValue] globalProperties, System.String toolsVersion, System.String subToolsetVersion, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection projectCollection, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Context.EvaluationContext evaluationContext) [0x00093] in <10b73e4bf233421cae439ef765e97ef0>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project..ctor (System.String projectFile, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[TKey,TValue] globalProperties, System.String toolsVersion, System.String subToolsetVersion, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection projectCollection, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings) [0x00000] in <10b73e4bf233421cae439ef765e97ef0>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project..ctor (System.String projectFile, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[TKey,TValue] globalProperties, System.String toolsVersion, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection projectCollection, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings) [0x00000] in <10b73e4bf233421cae439ef765e97ef0>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project..ctor (System.String projectFile, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[TKey,TValue] globalProperties, System.String toolsVersion, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection projectCollection) [0x00000] in <10b73e4bf233421cae439ef765e97ef0>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection.LoadProject (System.String fileName, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[TKey,TValue] globalProperties, System.String toolsVersion) [0x000f7] in <10b73e4bf233421cae439ef765e97ef0>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection.LoadProject (System.String fileName, System.String toolsVersion) [0x00000] in <10b73e4bf233421cae439ef765e97ef0>:0 
  at OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader.EvaluateProjectFileCore (System.String filePath) [0x0003f] in <21e2225264e848eb88f797c7e4a5cc78>:0 
  at OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader.BuildProject (System.String filePath) [0x0000d] in <21e2225264e848eb88f797c7e4a5cc78>:0 
  at OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectFile.ProjectFileInfo.Load (System.String filePath, OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectIdInfo projectIdInfo, OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader loader) [0x00015] in <21e2225264e848eb88f797c7e4a5cc78>:0 
  at OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager+<>c__DisplayClass29_0.<LoadProject>b__0 () [0x00000] in <21e2225264e848eb88f797c7e4a5cc78>:0 
  at (wrapper delegate-invoke) System.Func`1[System.ValueTuple`3[OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectFile.ProjectFileInfo,System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableArray`1[OmniSharp.MSBuild.Logging.MSBuildDiagnostic],OmniSharp.MSBuild.Notification.ProjectLoadedEventArgs]].invoke_TResult()
  at OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager.LoadOrReloadProject (System.String projectFilePath, System.Func`1[TResult] loader) [0x0001b] in <21e2225264e848eb88f797c7e4a5cc78>:0 

[fail]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Attempted to update project that is not loaded: /Users/finley/dev/dotnet/DatingApp/DatingApp.API/DatingApp.API.csproj</details>
```

#### C# log

```
Installing C# dependencies...
Platform: darwin, x86_64

Downloading package 'OmniSharp for OSX' (44721 KB).................... Done!
Validating download...
Integrity Check succeeded.
Installing package 'OmniSharp for OSX'

Downloading package '.NET Core Debugger (macOS / x64)' (51272 KB).................... Done!
Validating download...
Integrity Check succeeded.
Installing package '.NET Core Debugger (macOS / x64)'

Downloading package 'Razor Language Server (macOS / x64)' (50263 KB).................... Done!
Installing package 'Razor Language Server (macOS / x64)'

Finished

Failed to spawn 'dotnet --info'
```

### Environment information

**VSCode version**: 1.41.1
**C# Extension**: 1.21.9

### Mono Information

OmniSharp using built-in mono

### Dotnet Information

A valid dotnet installation could not be found.

My `dotnet --info` output:

```
.NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   3.1.100
 Commit:    cd82f021f4

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Mac OS X
 OS Version:  10.15
 OS Platform: Darwin
 RID:         osx.10.15-x64
 Base Path:   /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.100/

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 3.1.0
  Commit:  65f04fb6db

.NET Core SDKs installed:
  3.1.100 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]

.NET Core runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.0 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.0 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

To install additional .NET Core runtimes or SDKs:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There were two issues here!

1. VSCode does not have the permissions(?) to run shell commands (on behalf of extensions?) when opened via shortcut.
2. The paths generated by the C# extension were owned by root (as I had opened VSCode with `sudo` in my desperation when they were generated) and could not then be accessed by the extension when opened normally from the CLI. **I had to delete my project's /bin and /obj folders to fix this.**

Hope this is helpful for others!